# How to change Display Style Settings programmatically on Android LineageOS 15.1

Tags: java, android, android-settings

I  would like to change these settings by code, or at least, check which configuration are setup.

I've tried WallpaperManager with no luck.

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Comment: Unclear what app this is, but those settings should be stored in a Sharedpreferences file on disk

Comment: @cricket_007 i've found the solution. But please, do not downvote without a valid reason. This question really could help developers who use the same system.

Comment: I honestly didn't downvote, so don't go making assumptions

Comment: @cricket_007  sorry...

Answer (score 0):

This is a LineageOS system-only feature. To manage and control you must use [StyleInterface](https://lineageos.github.io/android_lineage-sdk/reference/lineageos/style/StyleInterface.html) API that comes on [LineageSDK](https://lineageos.org/Introducing-the-LineageSDK/).

Check it out here:
https://lineageos.github.io/android_lineage-sdk/reference/lineageos/style/StyleInterface.html